# List comprehension throws exception when list is empty

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a function that filters list items if their date is in the past (smaller than current date).

```
meetings = []
def clean_old():
    meetings = [meeting for meeting in meetings if time.mktime(meeting) >= time.localtime()]
```

When the list is empty, this code crashes.

Why does it crash? It says `for meeting in meetings`, and if meetings is empty then everything should be alright.

How do I fix it and what is the explanation for that occurrence?

Comment: Where is meetings initially defined? Is it empty or undefined? What exception is thrown?

Comment: [48]: meetings = [meeting for meeting in meetings if time.mktime(meeting) >= time.localtime()]

In [49]: meetings
Out[49]: []

Comment: @FogleBird, as I said, the list is empty and not undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you are seeing this exception:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'meetings' referenced before assignment
```

What you're experiencing here doesn't actually have anything to do with list comprehensions. This error occurs because you initially defined `meetings` outside of your function, but you are trying to assign it a new value inside the function.

When Python sees that a variable is assigned a value inside a function, it treats that as a new variable, *specific to that function*. This prevents the function from accessing any variables from outside of the function that have the same name.

Internally, Python is doing something sort-of like this:

```
meetings_outside = []

def clean_old():
    meetings_inside = [meeting for meeting in meetings_inside if time.mktime(meeting) >= time.localtime()]
```

You can understand why this would fail: `meetings_inside` is being defined in terms of itself. When Python tries to look up the value of `meetings_inside` to begin iterating over its content, it fails because it hasn't been assigned a value yet.

How to deal with this depends on which version of Python you are using, and there the initial value of `meetings` is defined.

In Python 3, you can simply add `nonlocal meetings` to the top of your function. This will tell it that you are referring to an existing variable named `meetings`, not creating another one.

However you are probably using Python 2, which does not have the `nonlocal` keyword. It *does* have the `global` keyword, which does the same thing but only if `meetings` is defined at the top level of a module: outside of any other functions or classes.

For example, this would work in Python 2 if you had nothing else in your file:

import time

```
meetings = []

def clean_old():
    global meetings
    meetings = [meeting for meeting in meetings if time.mktime(meeting) >= time.localtime()]

clean_old()
print meetings
```

```
[]
```

However this would not, because `meetings` is defined inside of a function:

```
import time

def main():
    meetings = []

    def clean_old():
        global meetings
        meetings = [meeting for meeting in meetings if time.mktime(meeting) >= time.localtime()]

    clean_old()
    print meetings

main()
```

```
NameError: global name 'meetings' is not defined
```

You would need to work around the issue. The simplest way would be to modify the assignment to be:

```
 meetings[:] = [meeting for meeting in meetings if time.mktime(meeting) >= time.localtime()]
```

This tells Python that you are replacing all of the values inside of `meetings`, but aren't creating a new `list` object. (The `:` syntax is called "slicing" and is partially described [in the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).)